# What is the difference between illegal substitution and too many men on ice in the NHL?

Tags: rules, ice-hockey, nhl

During the Montreal Canadiens vs New York Rangers game on April 16 2017, the referees called an illegal substitution on the Rangers, but strangely not too many men on ice. This happened during the second period as some players were changing shifts. How come this didn't result in a 2 minute minor? [This](http://www.habseyesontheprize.com/2017/4/16/15321216/canadiens-vs-rangers-top-six-minutes-montreal-takes-bite-the-big-apple-radulov-is-insane-highlights) is a reference to this incident, I wasn't able to find any other similar occurrence.

so I'm wondering what is illegal substitution and when does it happen? How does it correspond to the too many men on ice penalty?

Comment: I don't see illegal substitution on the play-by-play for the game on nhl.com.  Do you know when in the game it happened?

Comment: Second period. Take a look at the link I mentioned. That was the only place I could find a mention of it. I swear I'm not insane, it did happen. But how could it not be too many men?

Comment: I wonder if illegal substitution was initially called, but then was changed and not announced well?  That would explain no penalty and not being in the play-by-play record.

Comment: The commentators commented on it that this could happen. One of them described the reasoning, but it sounded just like too many men (at least to me)

Comment: Another thing that can happen is a player leaving the ice in the wrong location (not at the player bench).  But it's all speculation without more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Illegal substitution does relate to the too many men on the ice penalty and it is described in the NHL Rule book as

**Rule 68.1** Starts page 93-

> "An illegal substitution shall be deemed to have occurred when a player enters the game
>   illegally from either the players bench (teammate not within the
>   five(5) foot limit, refer to rule **74- Too Many Men on the Ice**),
>   from the penalty bench(penalty has not yet expired), when a major
>   penalty is being served and the replacement player does not return to
>   the ice from the penalty bench(see rule 68.2), or when a player
>   illegally enters the game for the sole purpose of preventing an
>   opposing player from scoring on a breakaway(see also Rules 68.3 and
>   68.4)"

[NHL 16/17 Rulebook](http://1.cdn.nhle.com/downloads/2016-17_RuleBook.pdf)

Comment: Is there any mentions when an illegal substitution will not result in any penalties?

Comment: Yes-  Rule 71.1  "Rule 71 – Premature Substitution
 When a goalkeeper leaves his goal area and proceeds to his players’ bench for the purpose of substituting
another player, the skater cannot enter the playing surface before the
goalkeeper is within five feet of the bench. If the substitution is
made prematurely, the play shall stop immediately unless the
non-offending team has possession of the puck -- in which event the
stoppage will be delayed until the puck changes possession. "

Comment: "There shall be no time penalty to the team making the premature
substitution, but the resulting face-off will take place at the center ice
face-off spot when play is stopped beyond the center red line. When
play is stopped prior to the center red line, the resulting face-off shall
be conducted at the nearest face-off spot in the zone where the play
was stopped.
In all other situations not covered in the above, a minor penalty
may result for “too many men on the ice” (see Rule 74)."